# Find the volume of the solid of revolution obtained by revolving the region bounded by some curve about a vertical line.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

I have a help regarding this question. If you could solve it I would be extremely grateful. I wrote buncha BS that doesn’t make sense.[image: The problem]
[image: What I tried]

Answer (score 1):

Why not use cylindrical shells.

Here's the setup:  $2\pi\int_0^{\pi} (x+\pi)(2+\sin3x)\operatorname dx$.

Comment: Thanks))) Where did you get the (x+pi) from?

Comment: The volume of each shell is $2\pi Ry\, \mathrm dx$. The $(x+\pi)$ factor corresponds to the radius, $R$, of each shell.